# Une société « décente » ?

Tags: sens, traduction, adjectifs, droit-et-justice, philosophie

On rapporte les propos tenus par un sociologue :

> On a l'air de gens qui ne sont pas très sensibles aux droits
>   fondamentaux, a affirmé le sociologue. On a l'air d'une société pas
>   très démocratique [en ayant] recours à la clause dérogatoire pour se
>   soustraire à l'examen des tribunaux. On n'a pas l'air d'une **société
>   décente**. ([propos](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/201905/08/01-5225241-laicite-on-na-pas-lair-dune-societe-decente-dit-gerard-bouchard.php)  rapportés sur Lapresse.ca)

La [*décence*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9cence) en français c'est la la « réserve et la mesure dans le comportement » ou le « respect des normes morales et des convenances [...] » (TLFi) et l'adjectif [*décent(e)*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9cent) peut aussi référer à ce qui est *régulier/acceptable*.

---

Vu la formulation du propos, entre autres la répétition de la tournure *avoir l'[air](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/air/1) de* dans les trois phrases, est-ce qu'on doit comprendre que le sens de *décent* ici est *sensible aux droits fondamentaux et démocratique* (la combinaison de l'antonymie des deux phrases précédentes) ; *réservé/mesuré* ou *régulier* en ce qui a trait à l'emploi d'un mécanisme d'exception (la [*disposition de dérogation*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1198696) évoquée dans la phrase précédente) ; qu'il y a personnalisation du mot *société* (pour *gens*, vu que les sens de *décent* semblent viser habituellement l'animé) ; s'agit-il d'un [anglicisme](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=decent&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) ; ou d'une référence à une notion provenant de l'influence d'une [œuvre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avishai_Margalit) particulière et incidemment dans un tel cas s'agit-il d'une bonne traduction ?

Answer (score 2):

Franchement, je ne suis pas convaincu qu'il s'agisse d'un anglicisme bien que la possibilité ne puisse être complètement exclue. La décence, dans son acception normale et française, est une notion adaptée au contexte (droits fondamentaux, démocratie).

Answer (score 2):

Simplement au ressenti, je pencherais pour une société qui, observée de l’extérieur, présente des faiblesses morales si évidentes, des méthodes législatives si cavalières<sup>1</sup>, des lacunes si criantes à la démocratie, qu’elle serait facilement jugée pervertie et inférieure, peu digne d’être imitée, voire considérée comme un exemple de fonctionnement à éviter.

---

1. <sub>Méthodes cavalières voire inconvenantes, selon le terme encore plus fort proposé par [Papa Poule](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/6011) en commentaire ci-dessous, qui ajoute que le simple fait d’avoir une clause dérogatoire est suffisamment inquiétant en soi pour que le fait d’y recourir par-dessus le marché mérite bien une telle dureté de vocabulaire. Si ce terme, **inconvenant**, n’est pas jugé trop fort, **indécent** ne sera plus tellement loin.</sub>

---

Je me permets cette lecture ou cette compréhension de la décence en songeant que l’indécence ne commence à exister que lorsqu’un regard extérieur se pose sur l’objet jugé indécent. Tant que personne ne connaît les turpitudes d’une personne ou entité sociale, celle-ci peut demeurer très respectable aux regards de ses semblables ou de ceux qui vivent dans sa zone d’influence.

Pour une société, comme dans l’exemple de la question, je perçois l’indécence possible dans le regard qu’y porteront les autres sociétés (ou leurs membres individuels).

Je rapprocherais le sens de *décent* (gardons à l’esprit que l’on parle ici de son absence) de celui de *convenable*, tel qu’on peut le voir notamment dans l’une des définitions de [***décemment***](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9cemment) au TLFi :

> D’une manière convenable, raisonnable.

Comment: Imo, your including "des méthodes législatives si cavalières"  is key, for (again, imo) a government simply having "une clause dérogatoire" to invoke is scary enough, but **daring to resort to using it** would justify the harshest synonyms of "cavalière" (eg, désinvolte=Qui montre une liberté excessive, voire inconvenante), if not worse (please note that I didn't add another "imo" to that last statement, for it's shared by all pro-democracy people, no?). Your "des méthodes législatives si cavalières" also made me wonder if "société" here means only the ensemble of people who will vote on this?

Comment: @PapaPoule Merci pour l'indication de la coquille. Corrigez sans demander de telles petites fautes. Je fais parfaitement confiance en votre jugement et votre français.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I almost did but wasn't totally sure whether to use "de" or "par."

Comment: @PapaPoule Oui, désinvolte serait un bon synonyme. Je ne sais pas lequel des deux conviendrait le mieux. L'un ou l'autre me semblent **décents**. Pour l'étendue de société, c'est difficile à dire... Peut-être que ça cible les gens qui ont recours aux faiblesses de certaines lois peu démocratiques pour imposer leur volonté unilatéralement, mais ça pourrait aussi s’étendre à la population complète, qui génère et élit d’aussi peu scrupuleux individus, et démontre mal ses capacités à endiguer de telles dérives autoritaires dans les nouvelles générations.

Comment: @PapaPoule Unrelated to language but the notwithstanding clause was a [requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_33_of_the_Canadian_Charter_of_Rights_and_Freedoms#History) by provincial governments to mitigate the impact the Charter might have when it was included in the Constitution. It can be scary indeed. Typically you would expect the stigma associated with using it to create an incentive for further tailoring the legislation so as to no longer require its use but it's possible nowadays majorities wear stigma like a chip on their shoulder, which is arguably even more scary...

Answer (score 1):

Après avoir longuement écouté ce monsieur, qui s'exprime essentiellement de façon impeccable mais qui comme tout orateur sans support papier pourra ne pas faire toujours le choix le plus approprié ou même en faire un tout à fait hors norme très occasionnellement — on constate dans son élocution un « ne … pas … aucun » et un « principal » à la place d'un « principaux » notamment — je pense que son choix de mot en parlant d'indécence ne convient pas exactement au contexte socio-politique qui suscite ses propos et que le terme que l'on escompterait serait plutôt « libérale ».

Addition relative à un commentaire de user [**survenant9r7**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36194/une-soci%c3%a9t%c3%a9-d%c3%a9cente/36197?noredirect=1#comment72165_36197)

Dans le monde bilingue du Canada, il y aurait une possibilité de cela puisqu'en anglais « decent » veut aussi dire « d'un standard ou qualité  suffisamment bon » mais il reste à apprécier la plage des concepts auxquels on peut appliquer l'adjectif selon cette acception ; je n'en ai pas une idée bien profonde en anglais, mais il me semble qu'en français, vu du point de vue français de France, on se limite à de tels concepts que la vie, la profession, l'avenir en tant que la vie de quelqu'un, le salaire, et d'autres concepts similaires et c'est un usage que je perçois comme assez solide ; il semble que l'idée de suffisance qui est associée dans ces cas-là n'a plus de sens dans le cas d'un concept comme celui de la société, en bref, la notion habituelle semble perdue par défaut d'un contexte habituel et donc j'ai l'impression de ne plus comprendre et je déduis que c'est le mot qui n'est pas juste. "Indécente" aurait été encore plus déroutant, il ne reste plus que l'option qui s'applique aux moeurs, la bienséance, et alors on ne pourrait parler que d'une socièté qui cultive l'indécence, la favorise, la tolère, entre autre possibilités,  à moins de restreindre la porté du mot à son sens de "entourage" (la société indécente des strip-teaseuses, par exemple) et celà n'a rien à voir avec le contexte. Ce n'est donc pas un indice selon mon point de vue. En Anglais d'ailleurs, je ne sens l'idiomaticité de « indecent society »   que lorsque « society » signifie « company ». Comme les acceptions de l'anglais et du français correspondent à peu près, s'il y a anglicisme ce serait au niveau d'un usage idiomatique de l'anglais qui constitue pour le français une extension et pas un nouveau sens, mais je n'ai pas conscience de cette extension. Le concept de société libérale me semble assez bien établi ; on trouve quatre occurrences du terme dans cet [article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lib%C3%A9ralisme) et si la société qui est reconnue comme telle l'est en vertu d'un parti politique qui donne le ton on doit préciser cela (parti  libéral, parti à vocation libérale, …) de sorte à ne pas laisser de doute quant à la qualité du libéralisme mentionné ; on n'entend pas par ce terme « société vouée au libéralisme de par la couleur libérale du parti » et d'autres dénominations du parti que « libéral » n'empêchent pas que la société donnée dans laquelle ce parti est au pouvoir puisse être catégorisée comme étant libérale ; il y aura peu de monde pour contester que les sociétés occidentales sont des sociétés libérales, considérées globalement. Je pense que si le terme « libéral » est connoté c'est simplement en vertu de son sens général, je ne vois pas la nécessité de la philosophie particulière du libéralisme attachée à un parti.

Comment: Les choses que tu as remarquées quand il parle sont plus intimement liées à la norme socio-linguistique en vigueur ici à mon avis alors que _décent_ détonnait beaucoup pour moi. Je le perçois comme très vieilli mais sa formation (du sociologue) et le contexte dans lequel il s'exprime m'empêche de le comprendre comme un choix naturel et spontané. Il se peut que le terme « libéral » soit connoté parce que c'est aussi le nom d'une formation politique. Remarque cependant qu'il n'a pas dit indécente, mais bien pas une société décente, il y a une nuance, j'aurais perçu indécente comme un anglicisme.